# WorksheetFunction IFERROR generates Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take data from a sheet and see if it's a certain Standard Deviation away from the mean.

I get an Error "1004" message. I'm guessing it's because I'm setting the Range wrong or that I misread how to use the For Each function for Ranges.

```
Sub testLimit()
    Dim Range As Range
    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim SD As Double
    Dim preRange As Range

    Set Range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    SD = InputBox("What is the Standard Dev. threshold?")
    For Each currCell In Range.Cells

        '****(ERROR)****
        preRange = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Range(currCell.Offset(-1, 0), currCell.Offset(-6, 0)), Range("A1"))

        If IsError(currCell.Offset(-6, 0)) Or currCell.Offset(-6, 0).Value = "" Or WorksheetFunction.IsText(currCell.Offset(-6, 0)) Then
            currCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        ElseIf currCell.Value > WorksheetFunction.Average(preRange) + WorksheetFunction.StDev(preRange) * SD Then
            currCell.Interior.color = RGB(105, 255, 105)
        ElseIf currCell.Value < WorksheetFunction.Average(preRange) + WorksheetFunction.StDev(preRange) * SD Then
            currCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 105, 105)
        Else
            currCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    Next currCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is highlighted when you have the error?

Comment: NEVER use a reserved word to declare a variable; particularly so in situations like `Dim Range As Range`. Use `Dim rng As Range` and change all subsequent references to either the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or the *rng* variable as appropriate.

Comment: *preRange* needs to be **Set** and it is not at all clear on what you are trying to do with the worksheet [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). In any event, IFERRROR doesn't play well in VBA; use the VBA [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) to catch errors.

Comment: with the IFERROR I want to catch an out of bounds error in case the cell is on row 2-5

Comment: OK, you need an out of bounds catch. I don't understand how `IFERROR(A2:A5, A1)` accomplishes that. Perhaps look into the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to avoid errors.

Comment: so looking at the currCell value, it's type is Range/Range as opposed to just Range

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the result of the `WorksheetFunction.IfError` function into a `Range` object:

```
preRange = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Range(currCell.Offset(-1, 0), currCell.Offset(-6, 0)), Range("A1"))
```

The `IfError` function returns the value of the cell, not a reference to the cell. Replace with:

```
Dim testCell As Range
Dim theUsedRange As Range

    Set theUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    SD = InputBox("What is the Standard Dev. threshold?")
    For Each currCell In theUsedRange.Cells
        Set preRange = ActiveSheet.Range(currCell.Offset(-1, 0), currCell.Offset(-6, 0))
        For Each testCell In preRange.Cells
            If IsError(testCell) Then
                Set preRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
                ' Found an error, no need to check the rest of the cells
                Exit For
            End If
        Next testCell
    ...
```